# Cannot get Homestead and Laravel working

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am getting 403 Forbidden when going to homestead.app but it works with homestead.app/public

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
   - ~/.ssh/id_rsa


folders:
   - map: ~/Desktop
     to: /home/vagrant/Desktop
     type: "nfs"


sites:
   - map: valiant.dev
     to: /home/vagrant/Desktop/Laravel


databases:
   - homestead
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I am about to give up and go back to codeigniter.

Comment: Have you added 192.168.10.10 to hosts pointing to valiant.dev?

Comment: Second shouldn't you be pointing valiant.dev to /home/vagrant/Desktop/Laravel/public folder?

Comment: I did another complete reinstall and left it default. My host has 192.168.10.10  homestead.app
192.168.10.10  valiant.dev

Comment: Also have this now sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public

Comment: Now on your Homestead folder do vagrant reload --provision and then vagrant up

Comment: Now I get 403 Forbidden, but works when I put /public

Comment: Now that you have updated homestead.yaml can you update question so that I can see it?

Comment: And are you using Windows? Which OS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136299/discussion-between-webbieworks-and-saravanan-sampathkumar).

Answer (score 0):

Update your `homestead.yaml` file on **.homestead** folder to this

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Desktop/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: valiant.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

#### Mapping folders syncing

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Desktop/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

This means that we are going to sync the **Desktop/Code** folder and **/home/vagrant/Code** folder so that files are updated on both folders.

#### Mapping website

```
 sites:
    - map: valiant.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```

This means whenever you are going to hit `valiant.app` folder it will check `/home/vagrant/Code/public` path

#### Updating Hosts

When you have successfully configured the above one, do `vim /etc/hosts` and add the following line to the file

```
192.168.10.10  valiant.dev
```

#### Reloading Vagrant

Once you have done all the above mentioned tasks, cd into the Homestead directory on home folder and do the following

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

above command will create(if doesn't exist already) on vagrant machine and map them according. Now do

```
vagrant up
```

That should get you working.